# Using PySpark, how we can output files per different schemas defined by some column value?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use pySpark (Spark 2.1.0) and have event log files in S3.

Event logs has json format (each line represents valid json) and each line has `event_id` property. Remaining properties vary pretty much depends on `event_id`.

e.g.)

`{"event_id": "1001", "account_id": 1, "name": "John"}
{"event_id": "1004", "account_id": 2, "purchase_id": 5, "purchase_num": 1}`

If I load this json file into DF at once, it seems all columns are included as schema properties for all rows. But what I want to achieve is divide the input JSON data into each event_id's rows, set a proper schema for each event_id with parquet format, then save files individually to analyze each events from the dashboard.

I came up with the solution that specify each schema and load whole json files as many times as a number of event_id, but thought this is not efficient. I can also allow all rows included, but I'm not sure if that is the common way.

Is there any idiomatic and efficient way to achieve this?